# Клавиатура поднимает разметку (рекламный блок должен быть в самом низу - закрываться клавиатурой)

Tags: java, android

[image]

В Manifest (adjustPan) не помогает!

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="c"
        android:text="@string/notes"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="none|text|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/writing"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id2"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй LinearLayout на ScrollView

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/475207)

Comment: Эмм..Как это не содержится?? 
С большой долей вероятности смена корневого LinearLayout(он единственный, потому я не уточнял) на ScrollView исправит проблему.


Если не поможет, добавь android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" в манифесте

Comment: безрезультатно!